# python __annotations__ from @property

Tags: python, oop, python-dataclasses, python-class

I want to get all annotations, including properties annotations.
what I get is only the annotations set for regular annotations:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Test:
    first: int = 1

    @property
    def second(self) -> int:
        return 5


t = Test()
print(t.__annotations__)
# prints: {'first': <class 'int'>}
```

Is there a way to get 'second' as part of __annotations__?
Maybe even to force it into __anotations__.

Comment: I think that would only be on the property getter itself - `Test.second.fget.__annotations__`. What's the context, how are you planning to use the annotations for?

Comment: I am inheriting from a class that can save the object as a json, but the way it works is using the \_\_annotations__ to determine what to save from the object into the json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `__annotations__` to get info on how to transform a dataclass into a json seems like a bad idea. It either locks you out of using transient attributes like `InitVar` or `ClassVar`, or leads to inconsistent and buggy behavior if you do use them. You should be using `__dataclass_fields__` instead.

That being said, sometimes your use case is simple enough that it'll do, or you're locked into it by one of your 3rd party packages that you can't easily improve, so here is one way to extend a dataclass's `__annotations__` with those that exist on its properties:

```py
class Test:
    var: int

    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return self.var + 2

    def __post_init__(self):
        cls = type(self)
        properties = [(x, getattr(cls, x)) for x in dir(cls) if type(getattr(cls, x)) == property]
        for name, property_ in properties:
            cls.__annotations__[name] = property_.fget.__annotations__["return"]
```

Creating an instance of `Test` will now include the property as if it were a regular typed attribute:

```py
>>> Test(1).__annotations__
{'var': <class 'int'>, 'x': <class 'int'>}
```

---

Just as a side note, the `__post_init__` code is executed during the initialization of every instance, even though strictly speaking it only needs to be run once on class generation, because `__annotations__` is defined on the class level. Since it's idempotent it won't break anything, but [here](https://gist.github.com/a-recknagel/bf44b50c216b10e5eb406a6aa19063eb) is a more confusing but arguably cleaner application of the same code which also works on regular classes.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much!